# Writing Database rules for Firebare cloud storage

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

So I'm writing rules for my database in firebase. And I'm trying to allow a person to delete his own post only. But when I'm testing it anybody can delete anyone's post.

I have tried writing if request.auth.uid==resource.data.User.uid but it doesn't work

```
 rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /posts/{postId}{
        allow delete: if request.auth.uid==resource.data.User.uid
        allow read;
        allow write,update: if request.auth.uid!=null; 
    }
  }
}
```

I tried simplifying it further by changing it to

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /posts/{postId}{
        allow delete: if request.auth.uid==1
        allow read;
      allow write,update: if request.auth.uid!=null; 
    }
  }
}
```

But still anyone can delete anybody's post. And obviously no one has uid as 1.

Here is my post collection

```
Content "Hello"
Title "Hey"
User
  displayName "Vikram Singh Bedi"
  email "vikrambedi_bt2k16@dtu.ac.in"
  uid "dCQvboYvffQ1kOqkMqgs2txNKvo1"
comments 0
createdAt 8 September 2019 at 14:10:31 UTC+5:30
favorites 0
```

I want only the person who created the post to be able to delete it.

Here is the code to delete a post

```
  <button
    className="delete"
    onClick={() => {
      firestore.doc(`posts/${id}`).delete();
    }}
  >
```

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your db structure

Comment: Please edit your question to include the [minimal complete/standalone code that anyone can run to delete a document](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen check edit

Answer (score 0):

How do you send a delete request?

For example if you are using [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin) to delete, then Admin SDK will bypass the rules.

Answer (score 0):

When you grant permission for a `write` operation, that grants permissions to all of `create`, `update` and `delete` operations.

You're combining a granular `write` rule with non-granular `delete` and `update` rules, which I suspect means the non-granular `write` rule wins out (since they're just OR'ed together).

If that is the case, use only non-granular write rules:

```
allow delete: if request.auth.uid==resource.data.User.uid
allow read;
allow create,update: if request.auth.uid!=null;
```